# start / re-start rails app from crontab RedHat 5.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, cron, redhat

I have got this funny constraint on a Redat 5.8 from our offshore IT team.

I have not been granted sudo or root user access. my current user has limited capabilities.

I have successfully install all dependencies for my rails application to run but now I need to ensure that each time the server restart arbitrarily that the application restarts automatically.

I have a script to do this for apache and mysql  below and these work very well.

```
* * * * * /bin/netstat -ln | /bin/grep ":8080" | /usr/bin/wc -l | /bin/awk '{if ($1 == 0) system("/path/packages/apache/bin/apachectl  start") }'

* * * * * /bin/netstat -ln | /bin/grep ":3306" | /usr/bin/wc -l | /bin/awk '{if ($1 == 0) system(""/path/to/mysql/support-files/mysql.server  start") }'
```

But here following the same pattern for starting my rails application using unicorn. it just does not work.

```
* * * * * /bin/netstat -ln | /bin/grep ":3000" | /usr/bin/wc -l | /bin/awk '{if ($1 == 0) system(" /bin/cd /path/to//current/; RAILS_ENV=production./bin/unicorn -D -E $RAILS_ENV -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb 2>&1 >> ~/log.log")}';
```

The above does not seem to get my rails application started.

I need help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Within your command above

```
* * * * * /bin/netstat -ln | /bin/grep ":3000" | /usr/bin/wc -l | /bin/awk '{if ($1 == 0) system(" /bin/cd /path/to//current/; RAILS_ENV=production./bin/unicorn -D -E $RAILS_ENV -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb 2>&1 >> ~/log.log")}';
```

Change the

```
RAILS_ENV=production./bin/unicorn
```

to

```
RAILS_ENV=production;/bin/unicorn
```

If this does not fix the problem then look in the mail for the user running cron or in the log file log.log and see whether that provides any clues

Comment: sorry what mail?.. how can i access mail.. Cheers

Comment: If you are logged in at the command line as the user who is running cron then simply type mail and hit return to read the first mail in the list. q to quit ? for help

Comment: Cheers Steve, i tried that. and foucn that i have no access to mail.. any alternative ?

Comment: Is there anything in the log file ~/log.log? Does the command work correctly at the command line?

Comment: If you run the following commands at the prompt what results do you get. `/bin/netstat -ln | /bin/grep ":3000"` and then run `cd /path/to//current;/bin/unicorn -D -E production -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
Found existing unicorn PID
shut down previous unicorn (1763)
unicorn started

Answer (score 0):

We finally got my head around it.

The error we found had to good with bundle/setup (Loadfile error)

All that is require to properly setup the Environment variables to using rvm's cron feature

Found here https://rvm.io/integration/cron

By running this command on the terminal it setup the right environment varaiables.

```
rvm cron setup
```

This adds the PATH, GEM_HOME etc etc at the top of the crontab.

With this in place we could then start ruby from crontab

I just want to say thanks to steve and holger.